# How can i add a div based on TIME using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a timer that will add or remove divs ( inline divs ) based on time function in Javascript or Jquery.

E.g With each second i want to add a div or remove a div.

Can i get some ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval`.

```
var diff = 1000, // how long between adds in milliseconds
totalTime = 0, // how long we have run
maxTime = 1000*60*60*5, // how long we want to run
interval = setInterval(function() {
  $(".parentDiv").append($("<div>new div</div>"));
  totalTime += diff; // keep track of all of our time
  if (totalTime >= maxTime) {
     clearInterval(interval);
  }
},diff);
```

Note that the time is in milliseconds.

And to get rid of it

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Beware that it will keep running, and if any of your actions take too long or slow down, you could find yourself with quite the mess stumbling over each other.

Comment: How to i control the time? Say e.g i have total of 5 hours in which each one will remove after 1 second

Comment: And also `setTimeout` method

Comment: @matty is right, `setTimeout` will run exactly once (and you can refresh it each time), while `setInterval` will run every x milliseconds until you cancel it.

Comment: If you want to run it for 5 hours, so keep track of the time. See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script>        
            var i = 0;
            var myVar=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);

            function myTimer()
            {
                document.getElementById('Container').innerHTML += "<div id='"+i+"'>This is the Div with New ID 'i'</div>";
                i++;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='Container'>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This Should Create a DIV each second inside the Div with id 'Container'

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of setTimeout(function, mili seconds)

```
var testTimer;
function timer()
{
    // Do your stuff
   testTimer = setTimeout("timer()",1000);

}
```

This will call your timer function every one second. and you can do your stuff in this function

To stop this timer function you can do

```
window.clearTimeout(testTimer);
```